# Removing values from a List<Object> that is part of a Map<String,List<Object>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

I have a `List<Coordinates> coordinateList = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();` that contains objects (`Coordinates`) associated with the values `X`, `Y` and `name`.

E.g.

```
Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.1, name=Series1]
Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.2, name=Series1]
Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.3, name=Series1]
Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.4, name=Series2]
Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.5, name=Series2]
```

etc

What I am trying to achieve is to create a Map of all the `Coordinates` grouped by name. This is done with the following Java 8 operation:

```
Map<String, List<Coordinates>> newList = coordinateList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Coordinates::getName));
```

Output:

```
{Series1=[Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.1, name=Series1], Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.2, name=Series1], Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.3, name=Series1]], Series2=[Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.4, name=Series2], Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.5, name=Series2]]}
```

Is there a way to remove the `name` from appearing again inside the `List` contained by the `Map`? I could remove it via the `toString` method associated with the object `Coordinates` but I need it for the grouping.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
Series1=[Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.1], Coordinates [X=0.1, Y=0.2]
```

etc

Comment: You will need one more class for representing a Coordinate without the series. Why are you concerned about the string representation?

Comment: Just don't call `toString`. Make another method that formats the result in the way that you need.

Comment: If I make a class without the name, are the names still going to be linked with the values so I can group them together?

Comment: Well, it is possible to just skip `name` info in `toString` method of `Coordinates` class, but that doesn't feel right (what if you will need that `name` info in other place while printing `Coordinates` instance?). Instead you can create separate method which will build string (or print each part on the fly) in form you wanted, by looping over each map entry and elements of lists.

Comment: OR, if presentation is only purpose of this map, maybe instead of collection `List<Coordinates>`, collect `List<String>` (where each String will contain only x, y info)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the grouping is made using `Coordinates::getName`, the `name` attribute is **not required** in the `toString()` method (as convention you may have it by you can remove it) then you'll have the output you want

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Coordinates [X=" + x + ", Y=" + y + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your code, you are using Coordinates.getName() method for grouping. In this implementation, the toString() method of Coordinates is not invoked.

```
Map<String, List<Coordinates>> newList = coordinateList.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Coordinates::getName));
```

It is safe to override the toString method of Coordinates class and remove the "name" field from the string.

```
public String toString() {
    return "Coordinates: [X=" + X + " ,Y=" + Y + "]";
}
```